# C # Connection with API with Token

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, django-rest-framework

I am connecting to a `REST API` from a project in C # but I don't know why I can't connect.

The API has a system that at 5 calls without TOKEN this message appears:

> {\ "detail \": \ "Request was regulated (throttled). Expected available
>   in 85856 seconds. \ "}

I try to apply the Token through the Header Authorization and nothing does nothing, I tried the classic way with HTTPClient and with the RestSharp component.
I add examples so that you can tell me or guide me that I am doing wrong and also a screenshot of the call using POSTMAN that does work with the Header Authorization.

HTTPCLIENT

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri ("https://www.URLWEB.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear ();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue ("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
AuthenticationHeaderValue ("Token", "{SECRETTOKEN}");

var result = 
client.GetAsync("api/urls").Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

return result;
```

RESTSHARP

```
var client = new RestClient ("https://www.URLWEB.com");

var request = new RestRequest ("api/urls", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader ("Authorization", "Token {SECRETTOKEN}");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute (request);
var content = response.Content;

return content;
```

[! [POSTMA: SUCCESSFUL TEST WITH TOKEN] [1]] [1]

[! [POSTMAN: FAILED TEST WITHOUT TOKEN] [2]] [2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0HX2.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMQKq.png

As a suggestion of a partner I have also tested the code that generates postman of the successful call that is:

```
var client = new RestClient ("https://www.URLWEB.com/api/urls");
var request = new RestRequest (Method.GET);
request.AddHeader ("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader ("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader ("referer", "https://www.URLWEB.com/api/urls");
request.AddHeader ("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.AddHeader ("Postman-Token", "e3492c30-0025-4324-a241- 
112c1c618bed, 0ddf0c91-f8a4-4a23-84bb-82bd4de554d8");
request.AddHeader ("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader ("Accept", "* / *");
request.AddHeader ("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime / 7.15.0");
request.AddHeader ("Authorization", "Token {SECRETTOKEN}");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute (request);
```

But this doesn't work either ...

I have tried adding ssl configurations with this code that I don't know if it is correct:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate 
(object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, 
SslPolicyErrors errors) {return true; };
```

But it doesn't work either ... I don't know what else to try, I have also tried another test API on the network with HTTPS protocol and it works perfectly.

I add more information, the API is created with python through the Django Framework I don't know 100% how Token authentication is done but I have been able to test the API call with a script in python and it works perfectly .... I add the code So you can see it.

```
class Urls (object):
  def __init __ (self, url, date, score, matchesi):
    self.url = url
    self.date = date
    self.score = score
    self.matchesi = matchesi

import requests
import io
import json

def object_decoder (obj):
  if '__type__' in obj and obj ['__ type__'] == 'Urls':
    return Urls (obj ['url'], obj ['date'], obj ['score'], 
    obj ['matchesi'])
  return obj

url = 'https://www.URLWEB.com/api/api/urls'
resp = requests.get (url, headers = {'Authorization': 'Token 
{SECRETTOKEN}'})
x = json.loads (resp.text, object_hook = object_decoder)

print x [0] ['url']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to get AddHeader to work; AddParameter however, has never failed me.

```
request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Token {SECRETTOKEN}", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

instead of

```
request.AddHeader ("Authorization", "Token {SECRETTOKEN}");
```

Comment: This I did not try in his day, and does not act differently.

I have already encountered the problem was in:

`var request = new RestRequest ("api / urls /", Method.GET);`

In the address of the resource that indicated the request did not add a / at the end this caused a re-address of api / urls to api / urls / and as a consequence make the functionality not run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A week later and thanks to several of your tips I managed to find the solution and it was silly as a house I show you:

```
var request = new RestRequest ("api/urls/", Method.GET);
```

In the address of the resource that indicated the request did not add a / at the end this caused a re-address of api / urls to api / urls / and as a consequence make the functionality not run correctly.

Thank you very much for the proposals have been very useful for learning and to take into account certain aspects that at least did not have.